# Error in Heroku addons:add sendgrid:starter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am very new to rails, please excuse me for silly questions.
So when i use the following command `$ heroku addons:add sendgrid:starter` the terminal returned me the error like this

"
!    No app specified.

!    Run this command from an app folder or specify which app to use with --app APP.
"

But, I've run the command from the root of the app itself.
So,I tried specifying the app too, which is 
`$ heroku addons:add sendgrid:starter --app sample`, where sample is my app.
And, I get the same error like this

" Adding sendgrid:starter on sample... failed

!    App not found.
"

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

The command you are trying to run looks fine, and it's just the app name that seems to be the problem.

Try running `heroku apps` to get a list of all the apps you have set up there.

Then double check the name of your app is actually sample.